# How to get doc2vec or sen2vec trained vectors in readable (csv or txt) format linewise?

Tags: python, arrays, vector, word2vec

I trained fasttext or Sen2vec, or word2vec model for my news collection in csv file, were each news have one line like that

```
0 Trump is a liar.....
1 Europa going for brexit.....
2 Russia is no more world power......
```

So, I got trained model and now I can happily get vectors for any line in my csv file like that 
(fasttext)

```
import csv  
import re

train = open('tweets.train3','w')  
test = open('tweets.valid3','w')  
with open(r'C:\Users\123\Desktop\data\osn-9.csv', mode='r', encoding = "utf- 
 8" ,errors='ignore') as csv_file:  
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=['sen', 'text'])
line = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    # Clean the training data
    # First we lower case the text
    text = row["text"].lower()
    # remove links
    text = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','',text)
    #Remove usernames
    text = re.sub('@[^\s]+','', text)
    text = ' '.join(re.sub("[\.\,\!\?\:\*\(\)\;\-\=]", " ", text).split())
    # replace hashtags by just words
    text = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1',  text)
    #correct all multiple white spaces to a single white space
    text = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', text)
    # Additional clean up : removing words less than 3 chars, and remove 
    space at the beginning and teh end
    text = re.sub(r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b', '', text)
    text = text.strip()
    line = line + 1
    # Split data into train and validation
    if line > 8416:
        print(f'__label__{row["sen"]} {text}', file=test)
    else:
        print(f'__label__{row["sen"]} {text}', file=train)
 import fasttext
 hyper_params = {"lr": 0.1,
"epoch": 500,
"wordNgrams": 2,
"dim": 100,
"loss":"softmax"}


model = fasttext.train_supervised(input='tweets.train3',**hyper_params)
model.get_sentence_vector('Trump is a liar.....')
array([-0.20266785,  0.3407566 ,  ...,  0.03044436,  0.39055538], 
dtype=float32).
```

or like that
(gensim)

```
In [10]:
model.infer_vector(['Trump', 'is', 'a ', 'liar'])
Out[10]:
array([ 0.24116205,  0.07339828, -0.27019867, -0.19452883,  0.126193  ,
 ........................,
    0.09754166,  0.12638392, -0.09281237, -0.04791372,  0.15747668],
  dtype=float32)
```

But how I can get vectors not as arrays for each line in my csv file? Like that

```
0  Trump is a liar..... -0.20266785,  0.3407566 ,  ...,  0.03044436,  
1  Europa going for brexit..... 0.24116205,  0.07339828,.... -0.27019867
2  Russia is no more world power...... 0.12638392, -0.09281237 
 ...-0.04791372,
```

Or like that

```
0   -0.20266785,  0.3407566 ,  ...,  0.03044436,  
1   0.24116205,  0.07339828,.... -0.27019867
2   0.12638392, -0.09281237...-0.0479137
```

Comment: I can give you a more specific answer, but just to be sure, you want a separate CSV/list with just the values of the words?

Comment: The library you are using for "doc2vec", "sen2vec", FastText, or word2Vec will offer options for looking up individual learned vectors, or in some cases combining vectors or calculating new vectors. So, the answer depends on what library or libraries you're using. Can you edit your question to clearly specify those by name, and to show which functions/classes of those libraries you've specifically used?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for yor input @gojomo. I use fasttext

Comment: @gojomo


import fasttext
hyper_params = {"lr": 0.1,
    "epoch": 500,
    "wordNgrams": 2,
    "dim": 100,
    "loss":"softmax"}
model = fasttext.train_supervised(input='tweets.train3',**hyper_params)
import fasttext

print(model['king'])

Comment: Hi @Andrew McGrail ! I want to separate columns in csv by ; or by ,

Comment: Use a library to create CSVs, there are several in Python. You should be able to just pass a row as an argument, and it will convert the lines to CSV for you. Whatever CSV creator you use will give you the option to use whatever delimiter you choose.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew McGrail ! Since I am very much new to python, may I kindly ask you to provide some small  chunk of code, wich I can use to google for solution

Comment: The answer should have all the info you need. Make sure to mark it correct if it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) Python library will get you started. The examples are very straight forward, all you should have to do is pass your lists as parameters and make sure it has the correct settings.

Loose example:

```
import csv 

#This should be a list of all the lists that
#you would like to write into the csv
master_list = []

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for item in master_list:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

This should at least get you started. I did light testing and it worked for me at the very least.

Comment: Greatly appreciate @Andrew McGrail ! Let me try it

Comment: Good. If it does work, make sure to mark the question as answered.